# How to force an element to have its child image width instead of its child paragraph

Tags: html, css

I made a basic example of my problem:

http://codepen.io/luksak/pen/Lbnga

I have a WYSIWYG editor where authors have the possibility to embed floating images of any width and height inside a blog post. These images have a description in the sibling `<p>` tag. This description's width should never exceed the width of it's image.

Here is where I am failing. I tried floating the child elements. I tried using `display: table-cell;` without success. Of course I could use some hard coded width, but that wouldn't work with my dynamic image sizes. Of course I could use JS to accomplish this, but I really think this should be solved in CSS.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display` value of `table` and a `width` narrow the `min-width` you wish.

The container will then expand to the biggest box width it contains (mostly like it will be the picture).

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgosi)**

---

```
.media-element-container  {
  display:table;/* will expand to fit the biggest element it holds within width and whole contenet within height */
  width:1px;/* see this as a min-width */
}
```

Comment: IE7 and below are out.

Comment: Well, that's ok for me... You are my hero!

Comment: @luksak Webkit requires a width not equal to 0/null. 1px will do : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBHiu

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to do it through the editor and create an area with specific width.

If you want to do it with js, keep in mind the the display will change in front of the user while the code changes the text display.

My solution will run **only if there are two conditions**: the `p` element has a specific class name (for identification purpose only) and it's directly after the `img` element.

```
var desc = document.getElementsByClassName('img_desc'); // find all descriptions tags
for (var i=0; i<desc.length; i++) {
    img = desc[i].previousElementSibling; // get the image element
    if (img && img.nodeName == 'IMG')
        desc[i].style.width = window.getComputedStyle(img, null).width; // set the width
}
```

I still think this is only the last resort and you'd better do it while creating/editing.

Note: IE supports `getElementsByClassName` only from version 9 and above.

Comment: I would rather not use JS for this since this is a pure layout problem that should not require JS to work...